# Angular 4: Is it possible to do Isolated Unit Tests with HttpClient?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-services

I thought I'd follow the [Angular guide for testing services](https://angular.io/guide/testing#services), but this is a new project without tests, and we just switched to using the newer HttpClient, and every example I've seen with that uses all the TestBed boilerplate, which I think is giving me issues in getting my tests running.

Is there any way to write isolated unit tests of services that use HttpClient?

The second part I'm wondering about is best practices. I'm still fairly new to unit/integration testing, and in the examples I've seen of HttpClient, they all use the HttpTestingController to return a mocked result. For my app, it's important that the API returns what the app expects, so shouldn't I test against the real service instead of pretending it comes back as expected? If not, then what's the value of writing tests for services?

Comment: What the real API returns shouldn't be important for unit testing. The reason for mocking is to take all variables that are outside of your control out of the test so you can focus on verifying the behavior of your component. That's the value of writing tests.

Comment: That's how I understand it too, so if my service does nothing more than do a GET and return an observable, is there any value in testing it? It's already taken 3 times as long as I thought it would to set up for HttpClient.

Comment: *all the TestBed boilerplate, which I think is giving me issues in getting my tests running* - this doesn't seem like a good reason to get rid of TestBed. TestBed is slower than isolated tests but it allows to test DI,

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible (or at least impractical) to use real HttpClient with isolated tests that don't use TestBed or other Angular injector.

In isolated test, HttpClient should be mocked to replicate real class, e.g.:

```
const httpClientMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('', ['get']);
httpClientMock.get.and.returnValue(Observable.of(['foo']);

const foo = new Foo(httpClientMock);
foo.makeRequest();
expect(httpClientMock.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/foo');
```